# How to publish the sql server's configuration

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I have a vb6 program connected to a SQL Server Database, which I configured to be shared in a network.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqB3GBKybng

and opened a port to allow the network access

My vb6 code to connect

```
 CN.Open "Provider =SQLNCLI;workstation id=192.168.45.100,333;packet size=4096;user id=MyUser;pwd=MyPassword;data source=192.168.45.100,333;persist security info=False;initial catalog=MyDB;"
```

I configured the database to be able to use openrowset statements and put these two codes

```
sp_configure 'show advanced option', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
```

and

```
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
```

The problem is when I want to publish my program, I want to Install the configurations automatically in my clients computers not manually.

Comment: I misunderstood your question so I'll delete my answer.  Are you asking how to install SQL Server with your application, or just configure it?

Comment: Both ... I want to instal it and configure it without installing SQL Server in my client PC

Comment: So your client will also have a server, and you want to install SQL Server on that box remotely?

Comment: No No ... He is just a client .. he don't need to install sql server , he just want to use the program
I have to Create the Database and  share it and allow the openrowset statement Automatically and without install SQL Server in the first open of the program . ....
Because there are many clients and I cant configure the database for everyone .. the prorgam should Create the database and configure it AUTOMATICALLY

Answer (score 0):

If the remote SQL Server exists and has already been configured to allow remote connections, all you need to do is run SQL queries against it during your installation.  This can be done with custom code or scripting host like PowerShell or VBScript run by your installer.  Below is a PowerShell script that takes the connection string as a command-line argument:

```
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string]$ConnectionString
     )

    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($ConnectionString);
    $connection.Open();
    $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced option', 1;RECONFIGURE;", $connection);
    $nul = $command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    $command.CommandText = "EXECUTE sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;RECONFIGURE;";
    $nul = $command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    $connection.Close();
```

If your installer program doesn't have native PowerShell support, a command like the example below may be used to run the script file.

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File ".\ConfigureSql.ps1" -ConnectionString "Data Source=192.168.45.100,333;User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPassword"
```

Comment: in Setup Factory .. I didn't Find PowerShell .... and How to share SQL Server Data Base Without install SQL Server 2005

Comment: @Abdex, without direct Powershell support, most installers support running a command-line EXE.  You could run the command-line I mentioned above like any other EXE to configure SQL.